# sizeWithFont returns wrong height in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

```
NSString *message = @"Can be a short string or a very long string";

CGSize rowSize = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGSize rowSizeBold = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

(rowSize.height and rowSizeBold.height are always equal) - this wasn't right - thx to jaydee3

the returned height is wrong and clips the text.

Any ideas?

solution: (works for Helvetica, Helvetica-Bold and any other font)

Reducing the width of the rowSize by the margin (15) returns the right height for UITextField.

```
NSString *message = @"Can be a short string or a very long string";

CGSize rowSize = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(235, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UITextField *messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 10, 250, rowSize.height);
```

thx to Ganzolo!

Comment: Are you sure about the names of the fonts?

Comment: They are displayed in an UITextField, where i can see that the font-names are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using UITextField to display font, you'd probably get this wrong result because UITextField has margin.

So in your constrained size you should remove the margin of the UITextField on the width component.

Comment: Thanks, this was the fix for my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy&pasted your code. Everything's fine:

[image: resulting sizes]

Comment: The Problem is that the height is always the same, but when there is a line break, the message displayed in Helvetica needs one line and the message in Helvetica-Bold needs two lines the height of both is still equal…

Comment: Then you have to give it the correct constraints. please post the code, which is NOT working... that code works as expected.

Comment: sry you're right. Probably it's really the margin-problem Ganzolo mentioned.